# Comparing Object Attributes to Integers in OO PHP?

Tags: php, types, integer, comparison

I'm having a small problem. In a class called reservation that has an attribute called reserve , which in the database is a tinyint(4), and an attribute kamp, which is int(10). I'm trying to do this:

```
if ($this->kamp == 387 || $this->kamp == 388 || $this->kamp == 389) {
   $this->reserve = 0; 
} else { 
    $this->reserve = 1;
}
```

Now my problem is, the code ALWAYS jumps straight to the else bracket. Even when I'm 100% sure $this->kamp is 387, 388 or 389.

Does this have anything to do with datatypes or am I missing something? I think the problem lies within this piece of code, since in my database there are objects showing up where reserve = 1 and the kamp is one of the three numbers I mentioned.

Thanks!

Comment: user trim around $this->kamp and check

Comment: `var_dump` kamp to find the type and value. Then make sure the loose comparison results in your expected outcome. If that doesn't solve your problem, install XDebug and step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will work for you.

```
$val = intval($this->kamp);
```

and then print or echo for result it will giving you value or not ?

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help, thanks. I've tried using intval, but it didn't help me. I'll try echoing/printing the result!

Comment: what it is return pr print also try with var_dump

Comment: Hmm, It seems like the variable is NULL or something. I'm using Exceptions to show the values, since that causes me to make the least changes to my programm. Any way to convert var_dump to a string value?

Comment: no the var_dump() function in PHP is used to display structured information (type and value) about one or more variables.

Comment: let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Last thing I said is not true. throw new Exception(($this->kamp==387) ? 'true' : 'false'); gives me a true.

I'm having trouble doing a var_dump.

Doesn't this mean my code should work? I'm so confused.

Comment: just add without exception like ($this->kamp==387) ? 'true' : 'false' and let see. what hpn